# how to filter JSON object in an array

Tags: node.js, json, filter, lodash, svelte

I am stuck in this problem for days.

Basically my JSON file contains one array with many items.

```
[
  {
    "table_schema": "A1",
    "table_name": "name1",
    "column_name": "date",
    "data_type": "name"
  },
  {
    "table_schema": "A1",
    "table_name": "name2",
    "column_name": "firstName",
    "data_type": "oid"
  },
  { 
    "table_schema": "A2",
    "table_name": "class",
    "column_name": "lastname",
    "data_type": "oid"
  }
]
```

I would like to get the distinct table_schema to display in the HTML. How do I achieve that?
As of now, I am getting:

```
A1
A1
A2
```

I want my output to be:

```
A1
A2
```

I am using nodeJS for the backend and svelte for the frontend.

Here's what i have fr now

Catalog.svelte:

```
    <script>
    let tableinfo = [];

    onMount(async () => {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/tables.json');
      tableinfo = await res.json();
      console.log(tableinfo);
    });
    </script>

  <div id='myData'>
    {#each tableinfo as info}    
      <p>{info.table_schema}</p>
    {/each}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help

```
const data = [{
    "table_schema": "A1",
    "table_name": "name1",
    "column_name": "date",
    "data_type": "name"
  },
  {
    "table_schema": "A1",
    "table_name": "name2",
    "column_name": "firstName",
    "data_type": "oid"
  },
  {
    "table_schema": "A2",
    "table_name": "class",
    "column_name": "lastname",
    "data_type": "oid"
  }
]

let unique_table_schema = new Set(data.map(d=>d.table_schema))
console.log(unique_table_schema)
```

This will return a `Set` with values `{'A1','A2'}`. If you want to convert it to an array use spread operator

```
let array = [...unique_table_schema]
```

Comment: Thank u! this works! however, how do i display each of the filtered array in the HTML? as of nw, its giving me "a,b,c,d,e" "a,b,c,d,e" "a,b,c,d,e" when i tried to for loop it in the html